# Jquery - Lag on pictures slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow, lag

Using Jquery I made a slideshow with pictures in the background on my webpage. In the CSS file I set the picture to fill the screen width. Then with the animate function I move the picture from right to left, and I put the proper delay for each pictures. It's working well, but after two or three loops, I begin to see a lag between the pictures, there is not a continuity between the pictures and the white background appears. The more you wait, the worse it is. Do you know what is the cause of this issue? What should I do to get it fixed?

Here is how I animate the pictures:

```
$(function() {

$('#picture2').delay(5000)
                  .animate({left: '0%'}, 1500)
                  .delay(5000)
                  .animate({left: '-100%'}, 1500)
                  .animate({opacity: '0'}, 1)
                  .animate({left: '100%'}, 1)
                  .animate({opacity: '1'}, 1);

$('#picture3').delay(11500)
                  .animate({left: '0%'}, 1500)
                  .delay(5000)
                  .animate({left: '-100%'}, 1500)
                  .animate({opacity: '0'}, 1)
                  .animate({left: '100%'}, 1)
                  .animate({opacity: '1'}, 1);

$('#picture4').delay(18000)
                  .animate({left: '0%'}, 1500)
                  .delay(5000)
                  .animate({left: '-100%'}, 1500)
                  .animate({opacity: '0'}, 1)
                  .animate({left: '100%'}, 1)
                  .animate({opacity: '1'}, 1);
```

Then I created the same function for each picture with the same delay, and I call the same function after in order to get a loop:

```
var animationslidepicture1 = function () {

    $('#picture1').delay(24500)
                  .animate({left: '0%'}, 1500)
                  .delay(5000)
                  .animate({left: '-100%'}, 1500)
                  .animate({opacity: '0'}, 1)
                  .animate({left: '100%'}, 1)
                  .animate({opacity: '1'}, 1, animationslidepicture1);

};
animationslidepicture1();
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: why reinvent the wheel, there are so many sliders which can fit your need

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't explain where the lag is coming from?